# How can I get ITIN If I dont live in US?

Tags: itin

I need ITIN for opening Paypal and other accounts. I am not US resident but I do have a registered US company. Is there an easy way to get ITIN? What are the specific requirements and how can I start the process.

Comment: Companies in the US usually don't need ITIN, they use EIN instead. Are you sure about what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get ITIN if you have a registered US company and you are required to report your earnings to IRS. The conditions might vary depending on your usecase. I would recommend getting help from Tax consultants.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Where should I look for tax consultants?

Comment: You can search online for tax consultants specific to your use case. I am sure there are a lot of sites.